# How to consume SAP Odata with Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to work on Xamarin forms and use it to consume SAP oData webservice. I dont seems to find any tutorial on this subject. This is what I need to do :
1) Consume SAP Odata and get the Data and insert it into local SQLite Table.
Can some1 provide:
a) What nuget to use for Xamarin forms for this task
b) reference links to Some Examples how to consume SAP Odata

Thanks

Comment: google "SAP odata c#"

Answer (score 1):

In order to work with SAP's OData services you should give a look at [this article](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/15/how-to-consume-service-layer-odata-services-from-net-via-wcf/).
It explains, step by step, how to consume SAP's OData services.

> How to consume Service Layer odata service via WCF
>    Add the metadata as service or file directly by selecting “Add Service Reference” into your C#/.NET based Microsoft Visual Studio project, the metadata will be validated automatically.
>
> Note: You have two options:
>
> Open a session with Service Layer before with the Login POST command, for example via PostMan or any other tool.Send a $metadata GET request with the B1S-WCFCompatible header property set to true.
>
> Save the metadata response into an xml file.
>
> Point to the metadata xml file from Microsoft Visual Studio Add Service Reference window:
>
> 2. Directly put the $metadata link into the Add Service Reference window (without opening a session before).
>
> You will be prompted to enter a User name and a Password:
>
> As there is no input for company name in WCF, the username and company must be combined as a User name.
>
> User name: {“CompanyDB”: “SBODEMOUS”, “UserName”: “manager”}
>   Password: your user password
>
> Microsoft Visua Studio IDE will use a tool named “SvcUtil.exe” to validate the metadata XML and generate proxy class for your usage automatically if validate passed. You can find all classes in “ObjectBrowser”.
>
> With the automatically generated proxy classes, you can program the required business logic of your application

I would suggest you to use [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client), is a great library that lets you handle, in a very simple way, your OData resources and operations. You can performs CRUD operations in Linq like context.